# Callback for location update

Tags: android, callback, location

I'm working on location service and want to get callback when I disconnect to network and re-connect again then get current location.
Is it possible in android to get location update callback once re-connected with network or wi-fi? Is fused location API provides any such callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically configure a broadcast receiver to get notifications of network change events.  For example you would add something like following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and then process notifications of associated changes in `MyConnectivityChangeReceiver`

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mypackage.MyConnectivityChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It would still be up to you then to make request to get location info when you detect change you're looking for.